# can a locally executed script run commands on the remote server?

Tags: linux, bash, scp

I've been experimenting with a patching process for deploying files to a webserver.

At the moment I'm using `scp` to get the zipped directory structure onto the webserver and then `cp -rf --backup=t patch* www/`

e.g.

```
user$ scp patch.zip server:~
user$ ssh server
// some welcome message, I have mail!, etc...
user@server:~$ unzip patch.zip
user@server:~$ tree
.
├── www
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 1.~1~
│   ├── 2
│   ├── 3
│   ├── 4
│   └── numbers
│       └── one
└── patch
    ├── 1
    ├── 5
    └── numbers
        ├── one
        └── two
user@server:~$ cp -rf --backup=t patch/* www/
user@server:~$ tree
.
├── www
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 1.~1~
│   ├── 1.~2~
│   ├── 2
│   ├── 3
│   ├── 4
│   ├── 5
│   └── numbers
│       ├── one
│       ├── one.~1~
│       └── two
└── patch
    ├── 1
    ├── 5
    └── numbers
        ├── one
        └── two
```

I'm not sure where I should be going to make this a deployment script, e.g. can a locally executed script run commands on the remote server? if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it certainly can.

```
scp patch.zip server:~
ssh server "unzip patch.zip"
ssh server "cp .... "
```

The question is: is it sane.  You can easily achieve this with passwordless ssh authentication (key-based).  But there's a good lot of risk to it.

An alternative would be to use methods like salt, ansible, puppet, chef, ...

Comment: I'm not sure how there's any more risk in automating this and reducing the chance of human error (forgetting the --backup flag for example) than in the current workflow. Or is it the current work flow you consider risky?

Comment: @Luke - I consider the use of ssh-keys in a scripted environment problematic. If the machine the script resides on gets compromised with a password-/passphrase-less login the data on the target machine becomes instantaneously available, too.  You could consider using a forced command on the far end to mitigate the problem to a large extent.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing that up fortunately the script will prompt you for the SSH password so the problems mitigated somewhat. I can see why using an SSH key to avoid this wouldn't be a wise idea.